# Why is my whipped cream dispenser stuck?

Tags: whipped-cream

I recently purchased a whipped cream dispenser (specifically, [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017XZYC2Q)), but it's been giving me some trouble and I don't know if it's just this one or they're all like this.

What I do:

- put in the prerequisite amount of whipping cream (1 cup), powdered sugar, and vanilla
- mix them up
- screw lid on
- put the dispenser tip on
- screw the N2O cartridge into place
- shake the dispenser vigorously a few times, then squeeze the trigger

Every time, right after I do all this, it comes out really nice, and usually will stay this way for a good 24 hours.

The problem: The next day, when I try to use it again, I'd shake the dispenser again before using but nothing would come out, despite me hearing the hissing sound. There's no way I could have used all that whipped cream the day before, so my guess is that the mechanism is clogged somehow. But if that's the case, what's causing it to clog? My guess is that it could be because I shake it too much (but I think I'm just following the instructions), or maybe it's too cold and it's just hardened up, but all I do is put it in the fridge so the temperature can't be that extreme.

Can anyone else enlighten me on what's happening? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have several of these and what you are describing is a common occurrence. 
As cream is either 'whipped' mechanically or put under pressure with a NO2 cartridge bubbles become trapped in the cream to 'fluff' it up. As the now whipped cream is allowed to rest the bubbles will slowly rise to the top and allow the gas to escape. While the pressure within the vessel remains mostly the same the gas is no longer suspended in the cream and does not get driven out of the container as you are expecting.

(note: do not 'just' add another cartridge of NO2 at this point. turn the canister upside-down and allow the pressure (and some of the cream) to escape (provide a bowl for the cream). Once depressurized you may open the canister and start over, I'm fairly sure you can reuse the cream if you choose)

Comment: That's an excellent explanation of what's happening. So then, does this mean that after a day's use, I have to store it upside down overnight so it can be good to go the next day? Does this also mean that each N2O cartridge will only last a day?

Comment: Your NO2 is only good for about an evening. Storing it upside down won't help (tried it :) )

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for your help. (By the way, I think those cartridges are N2O (nitrous oxide), not NO2 (nitrogen dioxide).)

Comment: NO2 is Nitric oxide,  nitrogen oxide is N2O. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrous_oxide

Comment: Nitrogen oxide is the general all-encompassing term for all nitrogen and oxygen compounds. More specifically, these may consist of nitric oxide (NO), nitrogen dioxide (NO2), and nitrous oxide (N2O) – what the cartridges are.